# How to solve : FATAL_ERROR System.FinalException: Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated

Tags: apex, emailmessage, casefeed

My Goal is to remove certain email address from **To** when user click on **Reply All**

```
Map<Id, EmailConfiguration__c> mapEconf =  C3S_EM_EmailConfiguration.getAllEmailConfigsByIds();
            List<String> EmailConfigs = new List<String>();
            
            for( EmailConfiguration__c EM : mapEconf.values()){
                EmailConfigs.add(EM.EmailServicesAddress__c);
            }
            List<String> AllAddresses = new List<String>();
            AllAddresses.add(emailMessage.toAddress);
            for (String Address : AllAddresses){
                if(!EmailConfigs.contains(Address) ){
                    AllAddresses.add(Address);
                }
                
            }
            
            if (sendEmailDefaults.getInReplyToId() != null) {
                
                EmailMessage lv_origMessage =
                    [SELECT FromAddress
                     FROM EmailMessage
                     WHERE Id = :sendEmailDefaults.getInReplyToId()];
                if (String.isNotBlank(emailMessage.toAddress) &&
                    emailMessage.toAddress.contains(lv_origMessage.FromAddress) == false )
                    
                {
                    emailMessage.toAddress += ';' + lv_origMessage.FromAddress;
                } else {
                    emailMessage.toAddress = lv_origMessage.FromAddress;
                }                    
            }
            
                emailMessage.toAddress = String.join(AllAddresses,';');
```

The error is on line :  **for (String Address : AllAddresses){** - Any suggestion ?

Another issue : How to eliminate *EmailConfigs* from ccAddress ? i couldn't do this : **AllAddresses.remove(EmailConfigs)**

Comment: you are adding to the list that the for loop is iterating over - either iterate over a different list or add to a different list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is trying to add new (potential duplicates) to the List of Strings that you are currently iterating over, this is not allowed.

To build a List of all addresses you can swap the List access such as

```
for (String emailConfig : EmailConfigs) {
    if(!AllAddresses.contains(emailConfig) ){
        AllAddresses.add(emailConfig);
    }
}
```

Or, you can use a Global list for the differences such as

```
List<String> globalList = new List<String>();
for (String Address : AllAddresses){
    if(!EmailConfigs.contains(Address) ){
        globalList.add(Address);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - but i'm stuck how to eliminate the *emailConfig* from *To*

Comment: my logic is : if  toAddress contain EmailConfigs then eliminate EmailConfigs from toAddress

Comment: @Fabien instead of using `List`, use `Set`. Email addresses should be unique and the [remove](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_remove) function is available in the System `Set` class.

Comment: The issue i'm facing that i couldn't iterate over the *emailMessage.ccAddress* , globallist contain all email addresses not only the emailConfigs ..